# Difference between horn and power resistor?

Tags: microcontroller, resistance, impedance, load

I have a circuit where my microcontroller is turning off and on a heavy load using a power MOSFET (I've also tried it with a MOSFET and a relay which yielded the same results). When I use a power resistor at 1.5 ohms everything works as expected. However, when I replace the power resistor with a car horn (measured at around 1.5 ohms using my multimeter), then when the circuit triggers the horn, I hear a horn sound for about a quarter of a second and then it stops, like the horn is somehow resetting my microcontroller.

Does anyone have any idea why a horn might act differently than a regular resistor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsoWEy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There's a big difference.   No doubt that it is EMI from the rapid dI/dt of the  discontinuous astable inductive resonator or basically a moving coil radiator with a cutout switch or as we call it " a noise generator"  Use twisted pair for EVERYTHING or Shielded TP (STP) cables and EMI filters, Big single wire loops make great antenna for noise radiation

Comment: And, as there is a coil in the horn, start with adding a fly-back diode.

Comment: I just ordered some diodes that should be able to do the job. Sorry, I'm not the most experienced EE, when it comes to an EMI filter, is that something I can just buy as a discrete IC or something an put in parallel with the horn?

Comment: Place a reverse polarity diode across the horn (does not conduct when horn is powered).  |Assuming horn is being powered on/off only (ie not tone being sent) . **IF** diode not enough then split R2 into say 1k+1K and add a small cap to ground at the junction. R1 should be unneeded. R2 tapped plus cap filters any back feed from gate. || Measure MAX current drawn by 5V circuit and add R in 12V feed to 7805 of about R = V/I = (12-8)/I . say 39 Ohms if Imax is 100 mA. This will drop some V from 12v to about 8V at Imax and act as an RC lowpass with C1.

Comment: POSSIBLY add a reverse biased zener FET  gate to source rated at somewhat above Vgate drive max - say 6V8 . This clamps spikes from drain which can turn on and destroy FET. .